# Create a dummy of a folder with a lot of files

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm creating a application that takes a `sourcePath` and creates a dummy of it on a `destinationPath`.

What i mean by that is that i want to copy a folder's structure and it's files, however the files must be empty so it can be done fast (i want to copy upwards of 700000 files at a time, so speed is very important)

Does anyone know how to go about this? here's what i've written so far (it only copies the folder structure, without the files)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sourcePath = textBox1.Text;
            string destinationPath = textBox2.Text;

            string cmdCopyFolderTree = $@"/C xcopy /t /e {sourcePath} {destinationPath} ";

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",cmdCopyFolderTree);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Speed of your disk is going to be very impactful. Why dont you use File class from System.IO or Directory

Comment: Are there any methods to copy only the file name and extension on the File class? or would i need to copy the name with the `GetFileName` and extension with `GetExtension` on a loop and create it on the other folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright here is a non recursive solution with multithreading:

- We rely on [`EnumerateFileSystemEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefilesystementries?view=netframework-4.8) to get recursivly everything in a given folder.
- We split every paths in two groups: folders and files.
- We create every folders in parallel in the dummy folder
- We create every files in parallel in the dummy folder

Code:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var oldPath = "foo"; // folder to copy
    var newPath = "dummy"; // folder to create dummies

    var oldDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(oldPath);
    var oldDirectoryParent = Path.GetDirectoryName(oldDirectory);
    var newDirectory = Path.Combine(oldDirectoryParent, newPath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectory);

    var paths = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(oldDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var filesAndFolders = paths.ToLookup(Directory.Exists);

    var directoryTasks = filesAndFolders[true]
        .Select(path => newDirectory + path.Substring(oldDirectory.Length))
        .Select(CreateDirectoryAsync);
    await Task.WhenAll(directoryTasks);

    var fileTasks = filesAndFolders[false]
        .Select(path => newDirectory + path.Substring(oldDirectory.Length))
        .Select(CreateAsync);
    await Task.WhenAll(fileTasks);
}

public static Task<FileStream> CreateAsync(string path) => Task.Run(() => File.Create(path));
public static Task<DirectoryInfo> CreateDirectoryAsync(string path) => Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(path));
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sFDKlB)

Comment: If you need any explication about the code, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
How do you deal with a directory if it has a "." on it's name?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out.Just use File.GetAtributtes

Comment: @FernandoAraujo Glad you figured it out yourself. I am not sure what the trouble was though: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uNyobj

Answer (score 1):

The Directory Class has GetFiles() and GetDirectories() functions, with a example Recursion:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles

Normally Disk operations would be disk bound, but I am not 100% certain in this case. Your operation would only affect the File/Directory Tables without actually writing a lot to the disk. And AFAIK, those tables are cached to memory because they are that fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
private void RecursiveCreation(DirectoryInfo dir, string destination, string subPath = "")
{
    foreach (var subdir in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        string dirPath = Path.Combine(subPath, subdir.Name);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(destination, dirPath));
        RecursiveCreation(subdir, destination, dirPath);
    }

    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        File.Create(Path.Combine(destination, subPath, file.Name));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RecursiveCreation(new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath), destinationPath);
```